# How to enable Key chain access group in Xamarin.Forms PCL project for ios

Tags: xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

I am working with xamarin PCL, [AD B2C Client flow project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzureAuthADB2CClientFlow)
When debugging on the iphone ios 12., catching the error message is :

> ex = {Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: The application
>   does not have keychain access groups enabled in the
>   Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to the
>   iOS keychain. The keychain access group
>   'xxxxxxxxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache

Note: xxxxxxxxxx is my apple Team ID

VS 2017 setup to Automatic provisioning

I have enabled keychain and try to save the token in in the cache

I have Keychain enabled and have added Key chain group like com.companyname.YYYYY in Entitlement.plist

i have added in info.plist is:

```
CFBundleIdentifier:
com.companyname.YYYYY

CFBundleName:
YYYYY


CFBundleURLName:
  com.companyname.YYYYY

 CFBundleURLSchemes:
msal[APPLICATION ID]
```

It not save the token in the cache throwing an error.

But it works when i change like this....

Key chain group like `xxxxxxxxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache` in `Entitlement.plist`

In `info.plist` is:

```
CFBundleIdentifier:
xxxxxxxxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache


CFBundleURLName:
xxxxxxxxxx.com.microsoft.adalcache
```

but this setup if i use in second xamarin project it might over wright the first project on the iphone

Please explain me what i have done wrong or is there any different way to do.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using  the same apple Team ID in your two different settings?  Key chain access group is used to share items between apps.

Comment: yes, both projects have same Team ID, Thanks

Comment: @rwahid Can you try with the latest version of [MSAL 2.7.0](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/2.7.0)? there is a TeamId fix there.

Answer (score 2):

This answer applies to MSAL versions 2.X+

This is happening because you haven't specified the keychain group you want your application to use. So it is using an MSAL default, which is probably not what you want. You need to do each of these steps and it looks like you haven't done the last one:

1. Set your application bundle name, for example `com.yourdomain.yourapp`
2. Add your application bundle name to entitlements.plist as a keychain group
3. *Specify the keychain security group* on the MSAL `PublicClientApplication` instance

For example with MSAL 2.x you might do this:

```cs
var authClient = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, authority);
authClient.iOSKeychainSecurityGroup = "com.yourdomain.yourapp";
```

Once you specify the keychain group it should no longer try to store to the keychain as that default adalcache group!

Details here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-iOS-specifics#enable-keychain-groups